# При входе пользователя на домен получение данных с другого адреса nginx

Tags: nginx

На сервере установлен nginx. Есть домен `api.mor.com`. Также есть скрипт, написанный на python и работающий на порту 7576. Необходимо, чтобы, когда пользователь заходит по адресу `api.mor.com`, то ему выдавало данные со скрипта.

Например, если пользователь зайдёт по адресу `api.mor.com/public_api/create_account`, то ему должны вывести информацию с адреса `94.138.85.120:7576/public_api/create_account`

Сейчас в конфигурационном файле присутствует такой код:

```
location /
{
    proxy_pass http://94.138.85.120:7576/$request_uri;
}
```

Но он не обрабатывает параметры в адресе после знака `/`. Как будто пользователь зашёл просто на `api.mor.com`. При переходе по адресу `api.mor.com/subscribe?email=user@email.com` пользователя перебрасывает на адрес `94.138.85.120:7576/?email=user@email.com`, то есть без `/subscribe`.

С http на https сделан rewrite:

```
rewrite ^ https://api.mor.com;
```

Может в этом где ошибка закралась?

Comment: P.S. Реальные домен и ip отличаются для безопасности.

Comment: По идее простого `proxy_pass http://94.138.85.120:7576;` должно быть достаточно, чтобы все параметры в адресе передавались как положено. Если это тоже не работает, то у меня есть подозрение, что проблема в python-скрипте

Comment: При переходе по адресу (api.mor.com/subscribe?email=user@email.com) пользователя перебрасывает на адрес (http://94.138.85.120:7576/?email=user@email.com), то есть без (/subscribe).
С http на https сделан rewrite `rewrite ^ https://api.mor.com;` Может в этом где ошибка закралась?

Comment: Скорее всего в этом, да, допишите конфиг с этим rewrite в вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С таким rewrite заменяете любую ссылку целиком на `https://api.mor.com` и теряете весь путь в url, попробуйте выдрать путь с помощью регулярки и потом подставить его через `$1`:

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ https://api.mor.com$1;
```

Ну и простой `proxy_pass http://94.138.85.120:7576;` ничего с url не делает и с заменённым rewrite должен нормально работать

Comment: Спасибо! Всё заработало, я просто добавил в rewrite на конце $uri `rewrite ^ https://api.mor.com$uri;`